# Getting list of stages for the current opportunity's RecordType

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

From an order of operations, I need to:

1. Get the Opportunity field values for **RecordTypeId** and **StageName** for the current Opportunity.
2. Get the picklist values for Stage based on the RecordTypeId of the current Opportunity.
3. Do some stuff with that data before displaying in my template

UPDATE: Thought I would share my revised code based on @sfdcfox's suggestion below...

```js
import { api, LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import STAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';

const fields = [STAGE_FIELD];

export default class Stages extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @track stageNames;
  @track error;
  stageName;
  recordTypeId;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
  wiredOpportunity({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.recordTypeId = data.recordTypeId;
      this.stageName = data.fields.StageName.displayValue;
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.stageName = '';
      this.recordTypeId = '';
    }
  }

  @wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: STAGE_FIELD
  })
  wiredStage({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.stageNames = data.values;
      console.log('Now I have everything I need...');
      console.log('stageNames', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.stageNames)));
      console.log(`Record Type Id: ${this.recordTypeId}, Stage: ${this.stageName}`);
      this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.stageNames = [];
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I explain how the wire life cycle works in LWC (see link), but I'll sum it up here: connectedCallback is synchronous, so the wire hasn't had a chance to call the getRecord wire yet, so the data is still null/undefined. To actually get the values, you'd typically want to add a wire handler (as opposed to just making it a property), and read the value when it comes across the wire.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use other tricks, such as using a `setTimeout` call, or a `await Promise.resolve()`, etc. It's basically a race condition you need to contend with. I can probably did up one of my old demo source codes if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Hoping the question is reopened after my revision clarified the problem a bit better so you can post your response as an answer that I will mark correct (because it was).